# Laravel returning error 419 after adding a virtual host on localhost

Tags: laravel, session, csrf, .env

I am working on a Laravel 9 Framework, I have added a virtual host on localhost **http://payment.test:8000** and then it started showing  `Error 419 page expired` after login page . 
The login is normally working when I use **127.0.0.1:8000**

**config/session.php**

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null)
```

**Login.blade.php**

```
   <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="row mb-3">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**.env file**

```
APP_NAME=
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://payment.test:8000
.....
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://payment.test:8000
.......
```

Comment: i don't think you need to put the port in the SESSION_DOMAIN

Comment: I tried with both methods and it didn't work .

Comment: Did you try paiment.test ?